# I couldn't get correct answer for my code

Tags: java

I have tried to get number of lines from a text file(.txt) using the following code

```
package com.practice.test;

import java.io.*;    
public class FileLines {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        try
        {
            File fl=new File("C:\\eGurkha\\agent\\logs\\agentout.txt");
            if(fl.exists())
            {
                FileReader fr=new FileReader(fl);
                LineNumberReader lr=new LineNumberReader(fr);
                int lineno=0;
                while(lr.readLine()!=null)
                {
                    lineno++;
                }
                System.out.println("Numer of lines in the file is : "+lineno);
                lr.close();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("File does not exsist");
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

But I could not read that file, the following output shows when I executing the above code

**Output**

```
File does not exsist
```

help me....

Comment: are you sure that this file exists ?

Comment: Yes, that file located in that location...

Comment: And the file exists and you have read permissions to it?

Comment: `that file located in that location.` - how did you check? Can you check with `dir` on a command shell and show us the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If *you're sure the file exists*, try to replace the char `'\'` with `'/'`.

Before:

```
File fl = new File("C:\\eGurkha\\agent\\logs\\agentout.txt");
```

After:

```
File fl = new File("C:\\eGurkha/agent/logs/agentout.txt");
```

Or, better:

```
File fl = new File("C:" + File.separator + "eGurkha" + File.separator + "agent" + File.separator + "logs" + File.separator + "agentout.txt");
```

*`File.separator`: the system-dependent default name-separator character, represented as a string for convenience. This string contains a single character, namely `File.separatorChar`.*

Comment: @kaviarasu Since you accepted this answer as the correct one, I would like to know whether this really solved your issue. Normally both `/` and `\\\` should work in an identical way, at least on Windows

Comment: @Andreas - Always use `File.separator`. Is the right way to proceed for the implementation of a platform-independent program.

Comment: It depends on the use case. If the file separator is visible to the end user, I agree. But in any case, it does not explain the issue from the question. `File.exists()` should return the same with either file separator.

Comment: @Andreas - For example, I use Linux (Debian) and `System.out.println((new File("/home/biagio/Java Workspace")).exists());` prints out `true`, but `System.out.println((new File("/home\\biagio\\Java Workspace")).exists());` prints out `false`. In this case Linux doesn't allow the `\\` separator.

Comment: Yes, you are right on Linux/Unix, but OP is obviously on Windows. Thats the reason why I am curious, but anyway ...

Answer (score 0):

Which Java-Version are you using, as there was a bugreport in 2004 mentioning, that `File.exists()` sometimes gives the wrong result on NFS-Filesystems

see: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5003595